# GeoServer SLD custom style displays PNG correctly but doesn't display SVG

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, svg

Trying to use an SVG file as an image for a point layer. I'm specifying the SVG in a SLD file that I upload to GeoServer. Everything works smoothly as long as I use a PNG, but once I swap to SVG, I just get grey boxes. The SVG was created from the PNG using inkscape and saved as a plain SVG.

SLD with PNG:

```
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource 
                  xlink:href="images/arrow.png"/>
                <Format>image/png</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>300</Size>
              <Rotation><ogc:PropertyName>course</ogc:PropertyName></Rotation>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
```

SLD with GeoServer:

```
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource 
                    xlink:type="simple"
                    xlink:href="images/arrow.svg"/>
                <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>300</Size>
              <Rotation><ogc:PropertyName>course</ogc:PropertyName></Rotation>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
```

SVG File,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   viewBox="0 0 4.8000002 51.136002"
   height="51.136002"
   width="4.8000002"
   id="svg3680"
   version="1.1">
  <metadata
     id="metadata3686">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs3684" />
  <image
     y="0"
     x="0"
     id="image3688"
     xlink:href="data:image/png;     base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAAY+CAMAAACdQCdpAAAAflBMVEWcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7Cc J7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7Cc     J7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7D/dP5H  AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAFiS0dEAIgFHUgAAAAJcEhZcwABzV4AAc1eAbhyk1oAAAAHdElNRQfh  BwYSLBizeGWtAAAGrElEQVR42u3cWVYUCQBEUTchyCBgWULG/jfoabuP7UBBDTlEVt1Ywf1+H/Hh  w2h7+VC5fOtkBWvvPXayknzuZAVr3ayhk/WPKi+drGDttS+drH9VeexkBWuPXXeyUs4aOlnBendf  O1n/q/KlkxWsd3bbyfpVletOVrDWyPrWyfpdla+drGC9sc+drD9Vue1kBWttrJdO1t+qikD/CitY  O/bYyXpNVRDoX2UFa02soZP1umrxQL+DFaxX9qWTtUu1cKDfyQrWX7vuZGV1rKGTFaw/9rWT9ZZq  wUD/JitYv+22k/W2arFA/w4rWP2sb52s91QLBfp3WcH6uftO1vuqRQL9HqxgdbNeOln7qLLtZAXr  xx47Wfupct/JClYva+hk7auaOdDvzQrW7hy/LGt/1ayB/gBWLp513cnKGbCGTlYunLXpZB2mmi3Q  H8jKRbNuO1mHqmYK9AezgtXG2nayDldl08nKxbLuO1nHqGYI9EexgtXEeulkHaeaPNAfycpFsh47  WceqJg70R7OC1cIaOlnHqyYN9CewcnGsp07WKaoJA/1JrFwY66qTlbNkDZ2sXBRr08k6VZWnTlYu  iHXbyTpdlatOVrCWZW07WWOoJgj0o7ByIaz7TtY4qtx0soK1HOulkzWWauRAPxorF8B66GSNpxo1  0I/ICtYyrKGTNaZqxEA/KitnznrqZI2rykMnK2fNuupk5UJYQycrZ8zadLLGV40S6Cdg5WxZN52s  KVQjBPpJWMGak7XtZE2jOjnQT8TKWbLuO1lTqU4M9JOxgjUX67mTNZ3qpEA/IStnx3roZE2pOiHQ  T8oK1hysoZM1rSrPnaycFeupkzW16shAPzkrZ8S66mTlYllDJytnw9p0suZQHRHoZ2HlTFg3nax5  VAcH+plYwZqOte1kzaU6MNDPxsoZsO46WfOpDgr0M7KCNQ3ruZM1p+qAQD8rKytnPXSy5lXlrpMV  rPFZQydrbtWegX52VlbMeupkza/aK9AvwMpqWR87WcH6uaGTlZWyNp2sZVTvBvqFWFkl66aTtZQq  HztZwRqLte1kLad6M9AvyMrqWHedrCVVbwT6RVnBGoP13MlaVrUz0C/MyqpYD52spVU7Av3irGCd  yho6WcurXg30BayshvXUyWpQvRLoK1hZCetjJytYb2zoZGUVrE0nq0X1R6CvYWUFrE+drB7Vb4G+  iBWs41jbTlaT6pdAX8VKOeuuk9WlyqdOVrAOZz13stpU/wX6OlaKWQ+drD7Vj0BfyArWYayhk9Wo  Ouri5tTeMdGwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw  sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw  sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw  sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw  sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw  sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw  sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw  sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw  sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw  sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw  sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw  sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw  sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw  sLCwsLCwsM6A9R3YIzudnkFx2gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== "
         preserveAspectRatio="none"
         height="51.136002"
         width="4.8000002" />
    </svg>
```

ERROR

```
2017-07-07 09:19:16,468 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Error occurred evaluating external graphic
org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException: file:/C:/stuff/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp84978b4f4881f40f/content-6d4985601cb52c21/data/styles/images/arrow.svg:0
The URI "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAAY+CAMAAACdQCdpAAAAflBMVEWcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7Cc J7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7Cc J7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7CcJ7D/dP5H AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAFiS0dEAIgFHUgAAAAJcEhZcwABzV4AAc1eAbhyk1oAAAAHdElNRQfh BwYSLBizeGWtAAAGrElEQVR42u3cWVYUCQBEUTchyCBgWULG/jfoabuP7UBBDTlEVt1Ywf1+H/Hh w2h7+VC5fOtkBWvvPXayknzuZAVr3ayhk/WPKi+drGDttS+drH9VeexkBWuPXXeyUs4aOlnBendf O1n/q/KlkxWsd3bbyfpVletOVrDWyPrWyfpdla+drGC9sc+drD9Vue1kBWttrJdO1t+qikD/CitY O/bYyXpNVRDoX2UFa02soZP1umrxQL+DFaxX9qWTtUu1cKDfyQrWX7vuZGV1rKGTFaw/9rWT9ZZq wUD/JitYv+22k/W2arFA/w4rWP2sb52s91QLBfp3WcH6uftO1vuqRQL9HqxgdbNeOln7qLLtZAXr xx47Wfupct/JClYva+hk7auaOdDvzQrW7hy/LGt/1ayB/gBWLp513cnKGbCGTlYunLXpZB2mmi3Q H8jKRbNuO1mHqmYK9AezgtXG2nayDldl08nKxbLuO1nHqGYI9EexgtXEeulkHaeaPNAfycpFsh47 WceqJg70R7OC1cIaOlnHqyYN9CewcnGsp07WKaoJA/1JrFwY66qTlbNkDZ2sXBRr08k6VZWnTlYu iHXbyTpdlatOVrCWZW07WWOoJgj0o7ByIaz7TtY4qtx0soK1HOulkzWWauRAPxorF8B66GSNpxo1 0I/ICtYyrKGTNaZqxEA/KitnznrqZI2rykMnK2fNuupk5UJYQycrZ8zadLLGV40S6Cdg5WxZN52s KVQjBPpJWMGak7XtZE2jOjnQT8TKWbLuO1lTqU4M9JOxgjUX67mTNZ3qpEA/IStnx3roZE2pOiHQ T8oK1hysoZM1rSrPnaycFeupkzW16shAPzkrZ8S66mTlYllDJytnw9p0suZQHRHoZ2HlTFg3nax5 VAcH+plYwZqOte1kzaU6MNDPxsoZsO46WfOpDgr0M7KCNQ3ruZM1p+qAQD8rKytnPXSy5lXlrpMV rPFZQydrbtWegX52VlbMeupkza/aK9AvwMpqWR87WcH6uaGTlZWyNp2sZVTvBvqFWFkl66aTtZQq HztZwRqLte1kLad6M9AvyMrqWHedrCVVbwT6RVnBGoP13MlaVrUz0C/MyqpYD52spVU7Av3irGCd yho6WcurXg30BayshvXUyWpQvRLoK1hZCetjJytYb2zoZGUVrE0nq0X1R6CvYWUFrE+drB7Vb4G+ iBWs41jbTlaT6pdAX8VKOeuuk9WlyqdOVrAOZz13stpU/wX6OlaKWQ+drD7Vj0BfyArWYayhk9Wo Ouri5tTeMdGwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw sLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCw sLCwsLCwsM6A9R3YIzudnkFx2gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== "
on element <image> can't be opened because:
URL data in unsupported format or corrupt at org.apache.batik.bridge.UserAgentAdapter.getBrokenLinkDocument(UserAgentAdapter.java:449)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.createRasterImageNode(SVGImageElementBridge.java:604)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.createImageGraphicsNode(SVGImageElementBridge.java:327)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.buildImageGraphicsNode(SVGImageElementBridge.java:177)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(SVGImageElementBridge.java:119)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:213)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(GVTBuilder.java:82)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SVGGraphicFactory$RenderableSVG.getGraphicNode(SVGGraphicFactory.java:406)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SVGGraphicFactory$RenderableSVG.<init>(SVGGraphicFactory.java:345)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SVGGraphicFactory.getIcon(SVGGraphicFactory.java:170)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.getIcon(SLDStyleFactory.java:1350)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.getGraphicStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:1259)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createPointStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:666)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createPointStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:546)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyleInternal(SLDStyleFactory.java:381)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:328)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:291)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processSymbolizers(StreamingRenderer.java:2569)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processFeature(StreamingRenderer.java:2453)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.drawPlain(StreamingRenderer.java:2309)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:1930)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:834)
at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:553)
at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:276)
at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:139)
at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:623)
at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:279)
at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:125)
at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:320)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor762.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:34)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:62)
at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:36)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:74)
at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:55)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:55)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.getMap(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor686.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:857)
at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:268)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:89)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: please include the SVG

Comment: Also is there anything in the log file when you turn logging up to geotools debug

Comment: I remember having problems with SVG a while ago. In the end, I did not use SVG. Which GeoServer version do you run?

Comment: Currently on 2.11, also @iant, I'm working on getting debug logs, but I'm running into a separate issue, I'll post them once I can.

Comment: since that is just an svg wrapping a png what advantage is there over just using the png?

Comment: also the svg doesn't open in inkscape for me so that may be the issue

Comment: I was having some issues with formatting the svg in a code box, but the file opens fine in inkscape and firefox. I was just trying to use svg as it looks better when scaled, no other reason.

Comment: Ok, got the debugging logs, error being thrown while opening the svg, adding to original post

Comment: @iant Basically inkscape isn't playing nice with the geoserver batik svg producer, I'll probably just use png for now.